# Linkedin login on ios

Tags: ios, authentication, linkedin-api

LinkedIn on iOS requires the LinkedIn login to be confirmed on their app. We hope to develop our app in such a way that users does not need to have LinkedIn app on their iPhone in order to login with their LinkedIn credentials and use our app. This is possible on Android so I just need this to work on iOS as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of third party libraries that help connect with LinkedIn using web-view and o-auth.

This is one such found in Github

https://github.com/ahmetkgunay/LinkedinIOSHelper

Please read http://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/